# How to change language from Kotlin to Java in updated new Android studio?

Tags: android-studio

*Is there no option of language choosing in this new UI ?

I'm new to Android dev , so i tried watching some editorials but they had the old UI but the new updated UI is quite different how to use this ?

Where's the alternative for activity_main.xml ?

Where's the alternative for main .activity.java ?

There's only one mainActivity.kt

I created my own Java class and layout XML file

but is that how it's done
*

[why's there no option to choose languages ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWSIq.png)
[there's no java main activity file at all like in the previous versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLTDR.png)

*what to do ?*

*I created my own Java class and layout XML file

but is that how it's done*

Comment: you have created a jetpack compose project in which there's no need of an xml file, the ui is also made using kotlin. The simplest way to go back to the old ui will be to delete this project and create an empty activity project